# How to make Firefox spellcheck the English language?

Tags: firefox, language, spell-check

My installation of Firefox spellchecks my native language, but I don't use that language very much. How can I make it spellcheck English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [British English Dictionary](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/british-english-dictionary/) together with [Dictionary Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dictionary-switcher/). The switcher allows me to easily switch between English and my native language.

Another way if you don't want to use addons is to download the English version of Firefox and use that instead of the one localized for your language.

Comment: +1 for Dictionary Switcher as well - great add-on

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's English on [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/) list. Unfortunately, the US English which I'm using isn't too good. Large number of words are missing.

Answer (score 2):

This Firefox add-in is all you need:

> [United States English Spellchecker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/united-states-english-spellche/)

There are other languages available as well.